# Render JSX element only when another element is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a page, the structure looks like this:

```
export default function MyBidPage() {
  return (
    <div className="children:mb-4">
      <AskToQualifyForm />
      <CreateBidSection />
      <DocumentsSection />
      <AboutBidderSection />
      <ExclusionGroundsSection />
      <SelectionCriteriaSection />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to hide `<CreateBidSection />` only when `<AskToQualifyForm />` is present in the page. How could I do that?

I was thinking about something like this:

```
{! <AskToQualifyForm /> && <CreateBidSection />}
```

but sadly it's not a valid code :(

*P.S.* A method without using state would be highly appreciated

Comment: You can use css, .`askToQualityForm + .createBidSection {display: none;}`, provided they have classes like these. Otherwise you will need contitions (using data from props, state, or context) to toggle the two components. More info can be helpfull

Comment: What controls whether `AskToQualifyForm` is "on the page"? Whatever it is, just invert it to know whether to display `CreateBidSection`.

Comment: i have a condition `if (!canAskToQualify) return null` which translates in: If an user is allowed to ask to qualify, then display that  component, if not return null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to T.J. Crowder's comment above,

```
export default function MyBidPage({...props}) {
  const { canAskToQualify = false } = props || {};
  return (
    <div className="children:mb-4">
      {canAskToQualify && <AskToQualifyForm />}
      {!canAskToQualify && <CreateBidSection />}
      <DocumentsSection />
      <AboutBidderSection />
      <ExclusionGroundsSection />
      <SelectionCriteriaSection />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If one is able to send the flag as a prop into the method, then it may be used to conditionally display the two components.

NOTE: This may be one possible way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. T.J. Crowder's comment helped me realize how to do it

Comment: Also since i'm checking if user is allowed to ask in the `<AskToQualifyForm />`, there is no need to use `canAskToQualify` on it.